# Is there a yeoman generator for SharePoint Add In's?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, spfx

I am coming back to Sharepoint development after 6 years. I initially thought that I needed to build a SharePoint Hosted Add-In. I want to build an app that operates within a SharePoint site. It will provision some lists, have a multi-step wizard, some charts, and a dashboard. It will be role based with different functionality exposed depending on the users role.

I have learned about this new SharePoint Framework infrastructure that makes it easy to spin up single page applications using Yeoman. Playing with it, it seems I only get two options: web part or extension. Within extension the options are Application Customizer, Field Customizer, and Listview Customizer.

Is there a Yeoman template for add in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is not yet. The roadmap shows they will be bringing add-ins to the modern sharepoint, but we dont know when.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/roadmap

You can either use SPFX WebParts or create SP Provider Hosted Add-ins for now. The SharePoint Hosted Add-ins will (afaik) work on the classic sharepoint pages for the moment.

Edit: SPFX could probably deliver what you need. If you need a full width webpart you can use it like so -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column

Comment: Looks like there is some unresolved bugs with full width web parts that could get in the way but, I am willing to give it a shot. Thank you for this.

Comment: The docs say that we can only use a full width web part on a communication site. I am in my dev tenant sharepoint admin. I don't see any way to create a communication site. I went into a sit collection and tried to add a new subsite and it is not listed there either. What is the secret?

Comment: Gah, have to use the new "preview" in Admin Center.

Comment: I guess there is no debugging support for this yet :-(

Comment: Yep, Com sites are only with the preview admin. For debugging SPFX you can read this -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/debug-in-vscode . Its not as good as VS, but it is better than nothing.

Comment: I decided to pass on SPFx for now. Thanks again for your help.